# Why some of my clients get 419 sorry your session has expired in Laravel and some don't?

Tags: php, html, laravel, caching

**laravel** version is **5.8** running on a shared hosting website running **Apache** Version **2.4.53**
and **php** version **8.0.25** on a **linux** operating system.

I'm facing this **issue** with **some** of my clients, where when they sign out, and login again, they get :

`"419 sorry your session has expired"`

I **personally** never got this error, and it's **frustrating** because I cannot debug the problem from my side and I have to do **trial** and **error** and tell them to test it.

**How they get around it :**

They tell me they **clear the cache from the browser** settings every time to make the problem go away **temporarily**, but then it comes back.

My question is : If I prevented caching to start with, by adding those lines of html code in every header, will the problem go away?

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: The 419 is related to the csrf token. you can counter it by forcing the browser to not cache the page, but you only need to do that for pages with forms in them that run POST requests.

Comment: @N69S is my solution of not caching the page correct? if there's other better ways please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with the no-cache headers, won't solve the problem.

There are two reasons, why you can get a 419 error:

1. The page was too long opened without sending a request, as such, the token expires
2. No csrf token is sent. (We can rule that out because you say it works sometimes.)

There exists a laravel package, which solves the problem: https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine

> Goal: Prevent forms from timing out when submitting them after leaving them on-screen for a considerable amount of time. (Laravel defaults to 120 minutes, but that is configurable and could be different site-by-site.)

Comment: I have a client who video recorded his screen signing out of the website and then signing in again and then got the 419 error. I saw it, he didn't wait for any time, and signed in right away. So that will rule out the possibility the page was too long opened right?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to laravel .env config..
verify if the SESSION_DOMAIN match your server domain

SESSION_DOMAIN=showldBeYourServerDomain

ps. domain string without http or https, and slash at the end
ex: instead of https://google.com, just google.com

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).